# Jenkins hangs when fetching code from Git

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I setup a new Jenkins job to fetch source code from a local Git. I can fetch from the server using `git clone` on cmd. When I fetch source code using Jenkins job it hangs with the following message for 10 minutes before throws time-out error

> Building remotely on Windows 2001 in workspace
>   D:\ASDF555\Jenkins\workspace\TEST_JOB Fetching changes from the
>   remote Git repository Fetching upstream changes from
>   git@test.test.texas555:team888/product555.git

I also configure path to use git.exe under `cmd` directory. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are your git clone address equal to the configured one in jenkins? I experienced somethin similiar. I usee on the commandline ssh://git@.... and on jenkins I only used git@... . After i added ssh:// to the address all worked fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your workspace is empty. I had this happen intermittently and then noticed it was only happening in one workspace. I ssh'ed into the jenkins server and manually deleted everything in the workspace.

Git no longer hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Login into the jenkins servers as "jenkins" user if you aren't already and clone from the cmd.
Check if it's successful? If it is, then try to run the job from GUI.

Comment: I don't think user is the problem here. I can use `Execute Windows batch` to clone the repository using `git clone` command successfully.

Comment: Can you clone it as the jenkins user ? I wanted to check if you could clone with jenkins as the user ?

Answer (score 0):

How long time does it usually take to make the clone from execute windows shell ?

I had a similar problem and i had to start jenkins with this option on windows. 
Find the jenkins.xml file and edit the line with arguments for java. 
you have to set the git timeout value to something higher than you have now.

```
<executable>java</executable>
<arguments>-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=400 </arguments>
```

Save the file and restart jenkins